# OpenStreetMap геокодирование

Tags: javascript, геокодирование

Требуется узнать координаты (широту и долготу) здания (например, найти координаты: Россия, г.Краснодар, ул. Ленина 16). Я пробовал: СloudMade и http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org. Они оба ищут отвратительно. Они смогли найти только Краснодар, Москву и т.д, а если искать глубже (например, улицу), то они не могут, не понимают, что я от них хочу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, либо нормальные сервисы для геокодирования для OSM и возможностью взаимодействия с ними через JavaScript, либо рецепты для CloudMade или http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org.
Вообще в проекте используется CloudMade.

Comment: А API Yandex карт не пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще API Спутник карт http://api.sputnik.ru/

У них данные тоже из OSM

Answer (score 1):

Если используете OSM, то как вариант, использовать универсальную js библиотеку Openlayers. Подходит так же для google map, yahoo, ArcGis.

[Здесь](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) примеры

Comment: Ситуация с геокодированием не лучше. Краснодар - находит, а улицу уже нет. Причем переставляя местами улицу и город, я вообще попал на Украину в какое-то село.

Comment: С улицами ситуация получше кажется в Yandex map api

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте геокодинг от 2Гис (http://demo.api.2gis.ru/).

- Ищет не только географические объекты, но и организации/места/объекты
- Отвечает в виде JSON и XML.
- Поддерживает реверс-геокодинг (поиск по координатам).
- Позволяет накладывать на поиск фильтры по информации, содержащейся в 2Гис (например отобрать магазины, которые работают в текущее время или принимают к оплате карточки).

Он бесплатен, не ограничен, данные постоянно обновляются.

Если нужен сервис с "автокомплитом", обратите внимание на  "Подсказки" dadata.ru (https://dadata.ru/suggestions/).
 У сервиса есть ограничения, но цены на коммерческие лицензии вполне гуманные.

Answer (score 1):

Официальная дока от OSM, как это работает.
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RU:Nominatim

По опыту, лучше использовать яндекс, т.к. здесь наиболее точные данные по СНГ.